# Insert sql fallo de sintaxis

Tags: c#, sql

alguien podría ayudarme con la sintaxis correcta de sql

```
  insert into  _EBR_Estado_Lineas (Npersonas)
                   values ('1') where Sistema = 'EBR-010';
```

Antes del where tengo el fallo pero no se cual puede ser.
Necesitaría insertar datos a mi base de datos. Comparto el codigo

```
 protected void Button_Entrar(object sender, EventArgs e){

            string sql2 = string.Empty;
              try{
               sql2= @" insert into  _EBR_Estado_Lineas (Npersonas)
                   values ('{0}') WHERE Sistema = '{1}';";

      sql2 = string.Format(sql2,this.txtNpersonas.Text.ToString(),this.sLinea.ToString());     
      this.Ets.Api.Util.Db.ExecuteSql(sql2);
       Log.insertarComentario("","insert", sql2);
   }
           catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 Log.insertarComentario("","Error", ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Seria bueno que puedas añadir la estructura en código de tu tabla "_EBR_Estado_Lineas" , por cierto cuando haces un tipo de inserción de ese modo, mayormente el where esta acompañado de un SELECT Y FROM  seguido del WHERE en tu inser into.

Comment: ¿Por qué requieres de un `where` con un insert eso no luce correcto?

Comment: ¿Nos compartes lo que intentas hacer?

Comment: Deberías utilizar la sintaxis: INSERT INTO tabla (campo1, campo2, ...) VALUES ("valor1", "valor2", valor3, ...);

Comment: Si eso me vendría bien, pero necesito especificar un fila especifica donde guardar mi insert con el where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta lo que se puede leer en esta otra pregunta: [MySQL direct INSERT INTO with WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948554/mysql-direct-insert-into-with-where-clause)

Podés notar que:

> INSERT syntax cannot have WHERE clause. The only time you will find
>   INSERT has WHERE clause is when you are using INSERT INTO...SELECT
>   statement

En tu caso, como también se comenta para el caso que te estoy citando, deberías pensar en un [UPDATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) no en un INSERT INTO